# Only activate OSGi component when an optional dependency is available

Tags: osgi

I have an OSGi bundle that declares an optional dependency on the org.osgi.service.subsystem package. It listens for the addition of a new Subsystem instance, using DS. However, this DS component activates even if the dependency is unavailable.

Is there a way to only activate this DS component if the optional dependency is available?

Basically, this DS component performs processing that is only relevant if there are actually subsystems present in the runtime. If there are none, and the class is not available in the runtime, this component should remain dormant.

Comment: Why is it an optional dependency if you don't want to activate the component unless the dependency is present? This sounds like a mandatory dependency.

Comment: Probably you should split your bundle into several bundles so that dependency does not have to be optional anymore. In my opinion when someone wants to specify an optional dependency, it is time to refactor.

Comment: @BJHargrave Well conceptually it is an optional dependency, because the bundle can operate perfectly fine if it is not present, however, if it is present additional processing needs to occur.

Comment: Then why is this question titled: "Only activate OSGi component when an optional dependency is available?" If you only want to activate the component when the dependency is available, then the dependency is mandatory.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. I want to perform some processing IF the dependency is available AND a Subsystem instance is registered in the service registry. This is the definition of the concept of optional to me, it can either be there or it can not be there. Either way things should work fine. I guess though, based on your comments, DS doesn't work that way, and so having an @Reference in a DS component makes it required.

Comment: An optional dependency means that the activation of the component is not held up by the absence of a dependency. If the dependency is present, it will be injected into the component before activation; if the dependency is not present, the component will be activated without the dependency having been injected. So if you require that the component not be activated until the dependency is present, then that is a mandatory dependency, which is what your title suggests.

Comment: Oh I see the confusion, I was referring to resolution:=optional in the manifest. If the subsystem interface referenced using @Reference is not available in the runtime, DS throws a ClassNotFoundException (or something similar, I forget what). I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. There is an even bigger problem that you bundle will not automatically bind to the optional package if it becomes available after you bundle resolved. You will have to refresh the bundle explicitly.

So the better solution in this case would be to move the component into a separate bundle that has a mandatory dependency on the subsystem package. It could then be installed together with the subsystem support.

Comment: Ok thanks. What is the point of an optional dependency then? I don't really want to have the users of this bundle have to install separate pieces. I think I should be able to do this using a ServiceTracker. I find it a bit odd that DS doesn't support this relatively simple use case.

Comment: Basically optional dependencies allow you to do what you plan but they are very tricky to use. For example you can not directly access such classes from an optional dependency as it would make the dependency mandatory. So a ServiceTracker can work but you need some magic. Apache CXF does such things but it is pretty ugly. 
See https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/bus/osgi/CXFActivator.java#L75-L90 and https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/bus/blueprint/NamespaceHandlerRegisterer.java